# How to add more than one Element in the same Attribute - XML (PHP Code)?

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP code that is running well, however not as expected.
**F.Y.I:** It´s running a function that is collecting submitted data from a form. (piece of code not included here, cause it´s OK).
I need to have 2 fields inside "Dados":  *name and email*, however only *email* is being recorded.

What should I do? Any clue?

**My actual PHP code:**

```
function my_generate_xml($posted_data) 

$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;

// build maximizer xml file
$xml_root = $domDocument->createElement('moduledata');

$xmlEntity = $domDocument->createElement('entity');
$xmlEntityTN = $domDocument->createAttribute('tablename');
$xmlEntityTN->value = 'Ent';
$xmlEntityFN = $domDocument->createAttribute('formatname');
$xmlEntityFN->value = 'Curriculum';
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityTN);
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityFN);

$xmlDefine = $domDocument->createElement('define');
$xmlDefine->nodeValue = $posted_data['nome'];
$xmlDefineN = $domDocument->createAttribute('name');
$xmlDefineN->value = 'ParamNome';
$xmlDefine->appendChild($xmlDefineN);
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlDefine);

$xmlSiga = $domDocument->createElement('SigaFiles');
$xmlSigaDN = $domDocument->createAttribute('Text');
$xmlSigaDN->value = 'SQG';
$xmlSiga->appendChild($xmlSigaDN);

// create node for current dados
$xml_dados = $domDocument->createElement('Dados');
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute',$posted_data['nome']);
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute',$posted_data['email']);
$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');

// Value for the created attribute
$domAttribute->value = 'Nome';
$domAttribute->value = 'Email';

$domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
$xml_dados->appendChild($domElement);
$xmlSiga->appendChild($xml_dados);
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlSiga);
$xml_root->appendChild($xmlEntity);
$domDocument->appendChild($xml_root);
```

**Desired XML output format:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<moduledata>
  <entity tablename="Ent" formatname="Curriculum">
   <define name="ParamNome">Thomas Edison</define>
   <SigaFiles Text="SQG">
    <Dados>
      <attribute domainname="Nome">Thomas Edison</attribute>
      <attribute domainname="Email">thomas.edison@gmail.com</attribute>
    </Dados>
   </SigaFiles>
  </entity>
 </moduledata>
```

**Actual XML output format:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<moduledata>
  <entity tablename="Ent" formatname="Curriculum">
    <define name="ParamNome">Thomas Edison</define>
    <SigaFiles Text="SQG">
      <Dados>
        <attribute domainname="Email">thomas.edison@gmail.com</attribute>
      </Dados>
    </SigaFiles>
  </entity>
</moduledata>
```

**Actual XML output format: (UPDATED)**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<moduledata>
  <entity tablename="Ent" formatname="Curriculum">
    <define name="Thomas Edison">nome</define>
    <SigaFiles Text="SQG">
      <Dados>
        <attribute domainname="Nome">Thomas Edison</attribute>
        <attribute domainname="Email">thomas.edison@gmail.com</attribute>
      </Dados>
    </SigaFiles>
  </entity>
</moduledata>
```

**PHP Code (Updated)**

```html
 <?php

function my_generate_xml($posted_data) 
{
    $domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
 $domDocument->formatOutput = true;

 // build maximizer xml file
 $xml_root = $domDocument->createElement('moduledata');

 $xmlEntity = $domDocument->createElement('entity');
 $xmlEntityTN = $domDocument->createAttribute('tablename');
 $xmlEntityTN->value = 'Ent';
 $xmlEntityFN = $domDocument->createAttribute('formatname');
 $xmlEntityFN->value = 'Curriculum';
 $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityTN);
 $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityFN);

 $xmlDefine = $domDocument->createElement('define');
 $xmlDefine->nodeValue = $posted_data['nome'];
 $xmlDefineN = $domDocument->createAttribute('name');
 $xmlDefineN->value = 'ParamNome';
 $xmlDefine->appendChild($xmlDefineN);
 $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlDefine);

 $xmlSiga = $domDocument->createElement('SigaFiles');
 $xmlSigaDN = $domDocument->createAttribute('Text');
 $xmlSigaDN->value = 'SQG';
 $xmlSiga->appendChild($xmlSigaDN);

 // create node for current dados
 $xml_dados = $xmlSiga->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('Dados'));

 $domElement = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
        $domElement->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['nome']));
 $domElement->setAttribute('domainname', 'Nome');

 $domElement = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
 $domElement->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['email']));
 $domElement->setAttribute('domainname', 'Email');
 
 $domDocument->appendChild($domElement);
 $xmlSiga->appendChild($domDocument);
 $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlSiga);
 $xml_root->appendChild($xmlEntity);
 $domDocument->appendChild($xml_root);

    // save it as a file for further processing
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($domDocument->saveXML()));

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();     

    $domDocument->save($uploads['basedir'].'/prorh/'.(int)microtime(true).'.xml');
}

?>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reorganizing your routine and append elements after their creation and not save all  `appendChild` calls at the end. Since you reuse the same variable names keep all components (element, attribute, values) together. Recall XML is a tree structure that grows from the root:

```
// build maximizer xml file
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;

// moduledata root element
$xml_root = $domDocument->createElement('moduledata');
$domDocument->appendChild($xml_root);                          

// entity element
$xmlEntity = $domDocument->createElement('entity');
$xml_root->appendChild($xmlEntity);    
$xmlEntityTN = $domDocument->createAttribute('tablename');
$xmlEntityTN->value = 'Ent';
$xmlEntityFN = $domDocument->createAttribute('formatname');
$xmlEntityFN->value = 'Curriculum';
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityTN);
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityFN);

// define element
$xmlDefine = $domDocument->createElement('define');
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlDefine);   
$xmlDefine->nodeValue = $posted_data['nome'];
$xmlDefineN = $domDocument->createAttribute('name');
$xmlDefineN->value = 'ParamNome';
$xmlDefine->appendChild($xmlDefineN);

// SigaFiles element
$xmlSiga = $domDocument->createElement('SigaFiles');
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlSiga);  
$xmlSigaDN = $domDocument->createAttribute('Text');
$xmlSigaDN->value = 'SQG';
$xmlSiga->appendChild($xmlSigaDN);   

// dados element
$xml_dados = $domDocument->createElement('Dados');
$xmlSiga->appendChild($xml_dados);   

   // attribute child nodes
   $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['nome']);
   $domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
   $domAttribute->value = 'Nome';
   $domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
   $xml_dados->appendChild($domElement);                         

   $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['email']);
   $domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
   $domAttribute->value = 'Email';
   $domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
   $xml_dados->appendChild($domElement);                        

// OUTPUT TREE TO STRING
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $domDocument->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You override the `$domElement` variable without appending the node.

```
// create node for current dados
$xml_dados = $domDocument->createElement('Dados');
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute',$posted_data['nome']);
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute',$posted_data['email']);
$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
```

I suggest nesting the `create*` calls inside `appendChild()` calls.

```
// create node for current dados
$xml_dados = $xmlSiga->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('Dados'));

$domElement = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$domElement->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['nome']));
$domElement->setAttribute('domainname', 'Nome');

$domElement = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$domElement->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['email']));
$domElement->setAttribute('domainname', 'Email');
```

You do not need to create attributes as nodes, `DOMElement::setAttribute()` works just fine for that. But you should create text content as nodes. The second argument of DOMDocument::createElement() is broken and escapes only some special characters.

Comment: it´s still not working, please refer to my actual code after the updates (see original post)